# "Want someone to do something" vs. "want someone doing something"

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

I always thought that when a person wants something done by another person, I use the infiitive after the object pronoun. But in the 16th episode of the 7th episode of *Friends* Ross use used a gerund. Here it is:

> Ross: I will be! Listen, I don’t want you **teaching** my son that stuff anymore. Okay?

Would the meaning somehow change if he said *I don't want you to teach...*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*If compared, both of the sentences have a slightly different meaning.*

***a to-infinitive** along with "want", an intention verb, would suggest that a person wants another person to do something in the future, while **an -ing** would emphasize that someone wants somebody to continue or stop doing something which depends upon whether you use a negative or affirmative auxiliary.*

***Conclusion:***

> *I don **'t** want you teaching my son that stuff [anymore/ever again]. ***( " The end position adverbs certainly imply that the speaker wants you to stop
> teaching her son [ since you have probably been teaching him for a
> long while ] )***;*

WHEREAS

> *I don **'t** want you to teach my son that stuff [ever]. **( "implies a future event" );***

*Furthermore, we can use the past participle after an object. e.g.*

> *I **want** the job **finished** by tomorrow!*
>
> *You **don't** want him **dead** seeing that his parents will come after you.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you tell me if it work wih the verb "believe"? For example: "I don't want you believing in such stuff."

Comment: The same applies for *any verb followed by "want" verb*

Comment: It's a very interesting concept. I wonder what other natives think. I also wonder if it's impossible or incorrect to sat "I don't want you to teach me..." meaning that the teaching is up and running. It feels that it's also possible.

Comment: @user1425 Absolutely. It was hard to split hairs. I agree with you - it could mean that too. It really depends on the approach sometimes. People would prefer to say one over another. I wasn't paying much attention to every possible interpretation but thx for your feedback.